# Flutter#2 : How can i achieve this in flutter?

Tags: flutter

**I want to print out a list of "item" by creating a listview inside my code**

> 

```
return Container(
  color: Palette.scienceBlue,
  child: Visibility(
    replacement: DevicePage(),
    visible: scanDeviceProvider.getVisible,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        const AppBarSideBarAndAddButton(),
        
        SizedBox(child: Container(
        // I need to print a list of "items" here
    )),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

> 

```
Future<void> onScan(dynamic data) async {
  var dataResponse = DataResponse.fromJson(data);
  print(dataResponse.toJson());
  List<dynamic> dt = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(dataResponse.data).toString());
  dt.forEach((element) {
    var item = Data.fromJson(element);

    print(item.model_Name);
  });
}
```

> 

i tried with `listview.buider` but got quite a few errors.
i have a function to get data from json file is onScan and i want to read `item.model_Name` in this function displayed on the screen
how can i do it?

Comment: What are the errors you got in `ListView`

Comment: I'm still having trouble calling the "item" in the 'container'.
I still don't know how to create 'listview' in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `onScan` to return the list of `Data`.

```
Future<List<Data>> onScan(dynamic data) async {
  var dataResponse = DataResponse.fromJson(data);
  print(dataResponse.toJson());
  List<dynamic> dt = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(dataResponse.data).toString());
  return dt.map((element) => Data.fromJson(element)).toList();
}
```

With this you can use the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to display the data in your Listview.

```
FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
  future: onScan(data),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Data>> snapshot){
     if (snapshot.hasData) {
       final List<Data> scannedData = snapshot.data;
       return ListView(...)
     } else {
       ...
     }
  }
)
```

You can then access your items with `scannedData`.

Comment: I used it and changed it a bit, as a result I was able to print out a string of elements in the list. However, I cannot access each element in the list. Can you help me. Below is my code:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/15Krtgx3BSXfQ5M7PtcCTmJfYVbFchOWWsWZ_F9PPId8/edit?usp=sharing